# Using "And" , "Or" operators in Xquery

Tags: xquery, xpath-2.0

let us consider an example,

```
<li>
    <div id="comments-list-245667" class="comments yui-u">
        <h3><span class="fn n">Ram</span></h3>
    </div>
    <div id="comments-list-245687" class="comments yui-u">
        <h3><span class="fn n"><a href='http://www.xyz.com' rel='external nofollow' class='url url'>laxman</a></span></h3>
    </div>
 </li>
```

Now how to get both "Ram" and "laxman" from the nodes using "and" or "or" operators.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Use**:

```
/*/*/h3/(span[not(*)] | span/a)/string()
```

This produces a sequence of the string values of every `span` that doesn't have an element child or of every `a` that is child of a `span` and that (the `span` element is a child of an `h3` element, that is a grand-child of the top element of the XML document.

**BTW, the above happens also to be a pure XPath 2.0 expression** (XPath 2.0 is a subset of XQuery).

Answer (score 0):

Assuming capitalization isn't important (in XML you have "laxman", in your question "Laxman") and you want to get the `<li>`s (otherwise, "and" wouldn't be reasonable, but if you want, move some axis steps in/out the predicate). Each line is an alternative.

or:

```
/li[.//h3//*[lower-case(.) = ("ram", "laxman")]]
/li[.//h3//*[lower-case(.) = "ram"] or .//h3//*[lower-case(.) = "laxman"]]
```

and:

```
/li[.//h3//*[lower-case(.) = "ram"]][.//h3//*[lower-case(.) = "laxman"]]
/li[.//h3//*[lower-case(.) = "ram"] and .//h3//*[lower-case(.) = "laxman"]]
```

The first or-alternative exhibits [XQuery operator's set semantics](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9196310/semantics-of-and).

Comment: Thanks for your answer, infact i've learnt a new concept, but i need "Ram"[which is in //h3 tag] and "laxman" [which is in //h3//a tag]

Comment: I updated my answer to generalize it. If you exactly need the `<a>`-tag, I'm sure you will be able to modify the queries yourself.