# Xquery version of "NOT IN" clause not working as expected

Tags: xquery, basex

I have an xml file which can be downloaded in the following link:
http://expirebox.com/download/483d465091802df68da10feddc1ec98c.html

I am trying to select all those movies without the styles of "live action" and "camp" in my movies.xml. To achieve this I am using the following query

```
for $movie in db:open("movies","movies.xml")/movies/movie
where $movie/styles/style!=("noir","anthology")
return $movie
```

However, all nodes in movies are getting selected. What is going wrong in my query?

Some experts are pointing out the inability of the standard not equal operator not working in this case due to the semantics of XQuery involved. However, my intention is to find a corresponding query of an SQL feature and not just understand the semantics.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Semantics of = and !=](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9196310/semantics-of-and)

Comment: hi i am using deep equal is as follows:
`for $movie in db:open("movies","movies.xml")/movies/movie
where deep-equal($movie/styles/style,("anthology","noir"))
return $movie`

but it is not working

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/4629660/14419

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`!=` uses set comparison logic.

For values that are not in that sequence, such as "foo", the expression `"foo" != ("noir", "anthology")` returns `true` However, the expression `"noir" != ("noir", "anthology")` would also return `true`. This is because  "noir" does not equal one of the items in the sequence, "anthology", even though it also equals one of the items in the sequence as well. The expression `"noir" = ("noir", "anthology")` returns `true` because "noir" is equal to one of the items in the sequence, "noir".

Refer to the specification:
https://www.w3.org/TR/1999/REC-xpath-19991116/#booleans

> NOTE: If `$x` is bound to a node-set, then `$x="foo"` does not mean the same as `not($x!="foo")`: the former is true if and only if some node in `$x` has the string-value `foo`; the latter is true if and only if all nodes in `$x` have the string-value `foo`.

Use:

```
where not($movie/styles/style=("noir","anthology"))
```

or:

```
where $movie/styles/style[not(.=("noir","anthology"))]
```